# Overriding g++ defaults from Rcpp package Makevars

Tags: r, g++, rcpp

I'm developing a package which currently needs to be compiled with `-O0` to be installed in a reasonable amount of time.

I've managed to overrride the `-O2` default in `/etc/R/Makeconf` by creating a one-line `~/.R/Makevars` file containing `CXXFLAGS = -O0`.

The problem is that the solution above is not portable (and I suppose it will affect all my other Rcpp packages). I'd like to get that change hardcoded in the package `src/Makevars` file so it gets shipped with the package. Here's a couple of things I tried adding to `src/Makevars`:

1. `MAKEFLAGS="CXXFLAGS=-O0" R CMD SHLIB *.cpp` (doesn't override any switches; I probably misunderstood the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Creating-shared-objects));
2. `PKG_CXXFLAGS = -O0` ([as expected](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Using-Makevars), simply adds `-O0` to the default tags);
3. Explicitly changing the standard to C++11 and C++14, updating the `*CXX*` flags accordingly.

What am I missing?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help you but I'm a bit puzzled *why* your package needs the `-O0` flag. Yes, the optimiser can be quite slow, but it shouldn't be *prohibitively* slow. And furthermore `-O0` essentially produces unusable code for production purposes. It's only acceptable for debugging, and often not even there. Generally it's a no-go. Are you *sure* it is an acceptable solution in your case? Is there nothing you can do to fix the speed of the `-O2` build?

Comment: @KonradRudolph, at the moment I'm just focusing on reducing compilation time. Haven't tried `-O1` yet or any other gcc switches for that matter, and we're looking into other ways to reduce the code footprint. In any case, my point is that I wanted to override the g++ defaults for that particular package, is this something an R package should not try to do?

Comment: There may be ways around it but *generally* a package should not override compiler flags, otherwise they might be incompatible with the R build options and lead to code breakage. In practice you can *probably* attempt something like `CXXFLAGS:=${CXXFLAGS:-O2=-O0}` but that would also not really be portable.

Comment: There is no per-package ability to alter the value in R's own Makeconf, you can only "add to the right of those values" via src/Makevars. I raised the before and eg Simon stated it as such.  In practice this has never been a constraint.  Oh, and none of this is Rcpp-specific.

Answer (score 1):

From the `g++` man page:

> If you use multiple -O options, with or without level numbers, the
> last such option is the one that is effective.

So adding the flag to the right, which you have already achieved, should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for digging that out -- I suspected as much, good to see it spelled out at a source reference.

Comment: That looks promising! Unfortunately, `PKG_CXXFLAGS = -O0` is adding the flag to the left of the `CXXFLAGS` on `/etc/R/Makeconf`. Tried playing around with some other flags and envars, but my noobness around compilers is preventing me from getting anywhere. :-/